# Should I put "intern" in my e-mail signature?

Tags: professionalism, internship, email

I'm currently employed as software developer intern and I'm in the process of evaluating different products for my company. For this reason I need to communicate with external companies through e-mail.

I notice that it would be much more professional to include a signature at the end of each e-mail with name, contact details, department etc. etc.

So my question is, should I specify that I'm an intern? I don't want to be treated "less" because I'm an intern so I guess this is where my doubts originate from. I'd rather just put "Software Developer" or "Developer" but I don't want to deceive others into thinking I'm a full-time employee. Thanks.

Edit: I asked my supervisor and he provided me with a standard signature (with no mention to me being an intern).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Ask your manager

Consult with your assigned mentor/reporting manager, regarding whether and what you should put in your email signature. Since you are currently an intern, you may not be aware of the practises followed in the company.

They will also assist you with any standard styling and fields to include in your email signature as most decent sized companies generally follow such conventions.

Comment: 1000 times this : signatures are usually well regulated in most corporate settings. Usually, no initiative is a good idea in that domain, bar asking what is the norm.

Comment: Aye. Whereever I worked so far, there was always some company policy about if, when and what email signature to use. The best advice here really is to ask the manager.

Comment: Many companies have an auto-signature pulled in from active directory or some other source that is appended to the outgoing email - so you rolling your own could end up with a weird double signature - even if this isn't the case: ask your boss.

Comment: Yes, ask. If you're worried about appearing like an ignorant new employee, then phrase the question "does the company have a policy on email signatures?" rather than "what should I put in my signature?" This makes it sound like you understand corporate culture.